# OpenCV contours not closing

Tags: android, image, opencv, image-processing, contour

Good day everyone!

I got an issue in regard of creating contours. I tried all configurations and unfortunately it is not possible for me to get one big contour of the object.
First file is loaded into bitmap and in the end the bitmap is loaded to file.
(Not shown here as it gives nothing).

Image before:

[image: img1]

Image after:

[image: img2]

The effect I would like to have is just the outer contour of the whole car or at least some approximation of it. The code I currently have (after looking everywhere) is this:

```
bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath), 500, 500);
    Mat src = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, src);
    Mat gray = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(src, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    Imgproc.Canny(gray, gray, 0, 1000);
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    Imgproc.findContours(gray, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++) {
        Imgproc.drawContours(src, contours, contourIdx, new Scalar(0, 0, 255), -1);
    }
    Utils.matToBitmap(gray, bitmap);
```

Comment: Canny does not produce closed contours, it just finds salient edges. If you need closed contours, use a method that produces closed contours, and don’t use Canny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have a bunch of complex colors in an image, always convert it to another colorspace before trying segmenting your object of interest.

In the example provided I converted the image to various color spaces like HSV, LAB and YCrCb (google them for more info). The hue channel in HSV image turned out to be for prominent for segmentation.

Here is my result:

[image]

Pseudocode:

1. Obtained a threshold image of the hue channel image
2. Performed dilation on the inverted image of the hue channel.
3. Found the contour having the greatest area coverage and marked it

**EDIT**

Here is the code:

```
import cv2

path = 'C:/Users/Desktop/'
img = cv2.imread(path + 'car.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)  #-- image was too big hence I had to resize it

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)      #-- HSV conversion
h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)

cv2.imshow('hsv Image', hsv)
cv2.imshow('h Image', h)
cv2.imshow('s Image', s)
cv2.imshow('v Image', v)
```

I also tried with LAB and YCrCb color space but the hue channel of HSV seemed to look better hence I stuck with it.

```
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(s, 87, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  #-- I had to check which threshold would be the optimum one to best separate the car
cv2.imshow('hue_thresh', thresh)


kernel1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
dilation = cv2.dilate(cv2.bitwise_not(thresh), kernel1, iterations = 4)   #-- performed dilation on the inverted image because the region of interest was not highlighted
cv2.imshow('dilation', dilation)
```

Now after having the possible region of interest I presumed the contour with the greatest area to contain the car.

```
_, contours, hierarchy =    cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
big_contour = 0    #-- contour with maximum area is stored here
max_area = 0       #-- to store maximum area

for cnt in contours:
    if (cv2.contourArea(cnt) > max_area):  #-- condition check to find contour with max area
        max_area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        big_contour = cnt

x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(big_cnt)     #-- store coordinates of contour with max area
cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('rect_img', img)

cv2.imwrite(path + 'rect_img.jpg', img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I would deeply appreciate you sharing the code.

Comment: @DAlajkonik Posted the code. Run it and see how each output looks like.to get a better idea !!!

Comment: thank you for your contribution, I really appreciate it. I analyzed all the methods and image stages and it gave me the idea on how to work with analysis and it is quite interesting! The problem appears when we add filter to dynamic resources: in this case the biggest contour since it varies in the photos, like here (all the progress shown in photos): imgur.com/a/mTNt1ah imgur.com/a/lPe2L1c Also it works good for a photo with many colors -- what about rather the same coloristic? Like this one: http://data3.primeportal.net/tanks/peter_van_iren/leopard_2_a6_nld/images/leopard_2_a6_nld_2_of_3.jpg

Comment: The idea proposed here is a basic one. For the image posted by you something more complex is needed, because the object of interest and the background fall in the same color space

Comment: I understand that. Sorry to bother, but do you have any idea on how to achieve that? I have been struggling with that subject for a while now and no success so far. Tried different channels, different color spaces and different algorithms, but they all fail. The idea i am trying now is to get mean of 50x50 area in middle of image (as object is in middle let's say -- it is a requirement) and thresholding all the image based on that mean +- random value.

Comment: have you tried the GrabCut algorithm? It is mainly used for separating foreground images from the background. It might give weird results but it is worth a try.